# Spam flagged posts should show better text than this

Tags: feature-request, support, moderator-tools

[image: I'm confused by this]

I get that if I onhover the title shows me that it was a spam flag, but when I first opened it I spent several minutes trying to figure out what was broken that I didn't see. Shouldn't there be a message for "this is a spam flag"?

Answer (score 3):

The white number in a red circle `①` is itself the indicator that it's a spam/offensive flag.

If you look at the non-spam flags, they have a different color scheme. On beta sites, for instance, they have a black number with a red background inside a yellow circle.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup><sub>*Which I find completely unreadable, but as it's easily fixed with a user stylesheet, I don't fret about it.*</sub>

Comment: Ok, I buy that they have two different themes, but I was totally confused when I saw it. Some text would be nice, besides the onhover. Or at least, this is why I posted the Q, to find out if I'm the only one.