# What kind of mod flag is this?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spam flagged posts should show better text than this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93007/spam-flagged-posts-should-show-better-text-than-this)

[image]

I'm guessing it's a "mystery" flag. Like a mystery shopper - a random invisible flag that's sent to evaluate how we respond in an unknown situation.

Just as long as there's a bonus<sup>1</sup> I guess that's OK ;)

<sub><sup>1</sup>(I once got a free pen for passing a Microsoft mystery shoppers test. It wasn't very hard. I worked in a dingey computer store on the bad side of town and this incredibly attractive young woman walks into the store (giveaway #1, most of our customers were men and immigrants who had spent less than a month in the country, which was why they were coming to the only place they could afford) and clearly knew nothing about computers and goes "So, umm, I want to buy Windows XP, but I'm not sure if I should buy Office or not. Can you tell me what the differences are?")</sub>

Comment: Is it a spam flag?  Hover your mouse over it (or check it in the chrome inspector)... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93007/spam-flagged-posts-should-show-better-text-than-this (if so, is this a dupe of that?)

Comment: @jcole - iinteresting, it's an Offensive flag. I thought they were reserved for comments only, cos I can't see any way to flag as offensive on an answer

Comment: **it is not welcome in our community** This answer contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech.

Comment: @jcolebrand, @Farseeker - it's the same question, because it's the same problem with the same icon—you can't tell which of the two it is until you hover over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the colour, that's a Spam/offensive post flag

[image]

Comment: Pro Tip - don't try flagging that if you're a mod on an innocent question just to see what it does.

Comment: @Farseeker What makes you think I've flagged it? Pro Tip: Don't assume.

Comment: I didn't mean that at all; sorry. I meant that *I* flagged an innocent question to try it out on and all sorts of bad things happened.

Comment: @Farseeker I see, apologies for the misunderstanding then.

Comment: all good. I can see how my comment could have been interpreted that way.

Answer (score 4):

Not all flags have messages associated with them.  Sometimes the flag itself *is* a message.  Look in the sidebar of the page, the types of flags are listed, and it also shows the coloring scheme.

Also, with most things on Stack Exchange, hovering helps.

Comment: Interesting. I was also confused by the tooltip description (which I wasn't looking for) of "Offensive" as that no longer exists as a flag on questions, but as jcole pointed out in the comments it's been renamed to "no welcome"